# Is there is a way to prevent browser DEVTOOLS from accessing source files of a website

Tags: html, httpbackend, web-developer-toolbar

As mentioned on the title , i am looking for a way to prevent what i am showcasing in the screenshot , it is bad people accessing things that are not even public yet

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNvEv.png)

Comment: If you don't want your website to be public, don't publish it to the public Internet. Host it behind a private network

Answer (score 0):

> i am looking for a way to prevent what i am showcasing in the screenshot

You can't.

> it is bad people accessing things that are not even public yet

You must be telling the browser about those resources *somewhere*.

Don't do that if you don't want the browser to know about them.

Comment: i've seen websites do it , look at the screenshot
https://ibb.co/HgWxwN8 
there is this one for example , and shows something like a popup in the top of the page saying " paused in debugger "

Comment: That image isn't showing what you think it's showing. That's not the JS source for the site.